# Mathematica 10.4.0 hang on startup, killing WolframKernel fixes it

Tags: linux, kernel-startup, installation

I just upgraded to Mathematica 10.4 (Site Home Use) on Ubuntu 15.10 (x86-64).  After entering the activation key and clicking Activate, I got a message "Activation was successful", and then the window disappeared and nothing happened.

Inspecting with `ps` showed that Mathematica was still running, with a number of subprocesses, some of which were `WolframKernel` processes.  `strace` showed that both were in an apparently infinite loop of `futex` calls.  Lacking any better ideas, I killed one of them (`kill -TERM` didn't successfully kill it, so I used `kill -9`).  A couple seconds later, I was presented with the license agreement screen, and was able to start using Mathematica.

Ever since then, trying to start it (running `Mathematica` from the command line) results in similar behavior: processes start but no windows appear.  Killing one of the `WolframKernel` processes (with `kill -9`) causes the following window to appear:

[image]

I can then click "New Notebook" and Mathematica seems to work normally.

Maybe this is a question for Wolfram Support, but I thought I would first see whether it is a well-known problem, or if there's something obvious I should try.

**Update.** With Mathematica 11 the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Even if somebody else had encountered this before (although I don't recall seeing it reported here), you should still definitely report this behavior to Wolfram Support; they will be interested in investigating further to see if it's a general problem.

Comment: We're investigating the issue. Thank you for reporting it.

Comment: Is there any update on the problem? I'm also getting it (Gentoo Linux, x86-64)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your network configuration having issues (ex: can't ping your hostname, bad DNS resolver, etc). For some reason Mathematica is extra sensitive to network issues and especially hostnames, even more when activating. I think it uses hostnames or mac address to bind your license to your computer,  but it can sometimes make a mess.

The simplest way is to set a hostname manually, put it after localhost in /etc/hosts and make sure it pings.

Then restart Mathematica and it should work